# Prove an inequality in the space of $L^{2}(\Omega)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, normed-spaces, sobolev-spaces

**EDIT:** First of all, I thank Calvin Khor's exhaustive comments on the inequality that I proposed regarding the semi-norm in $L^{2}(\Omega)$, which after his teachings and his final comments allowed me to realize that this inequality did not make sense for any semi-norm of $L^{2}(\Omega)$. For that reason I have modified my problem, changing from the semi-norm $|\cdot|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}$ in $L^{2}(\Omega)$ to the norm $||\cdot||_{L^{2}(\Omega)}$ in $L^{2}(\Omega)$. Again, thank you very much Calvin Khor.

> **Fixed issue:** My goals is to prove that there exists a positive-strictly constant $C_{0}>0$ such that for all $v\in H^{1}(\Omega)$, we have that $$||v||^{2}_{L^{2}(\Omega)} \leq C_{0} \left[ ||v||^{2}_{L^{2}(\Phi)}+||\nabla v||^{2}_{L^{2}(\Omega)}\right]$$
> where $||\cdot||_{L^{2}}$ be norms in $L^{2}(\Omega)$ and $\Omega=(0,1)\times (0,1)$ and $\Phi=\{0\}\times (0,1)$.

**My approach:**  Maybe I should use the Poincaré's inequality:

> **Poncaré's inequality:** Let $\Omega$ a bounded open set of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Then, there exists a positive $C_{p}(\Omega)$ such that: $$\color{blue}{\boxed{||v||_{L^{2}(\Omega)}\leq C_{p}(\Omega)|v|_{H^{1}(\Omega)}=C_{p}(\Omega)||\mathbf{\nabla v}||_{L^{2}(\Omega)}}}$$

We have that $$ ||v||_{L^{2}(\Omega)}^{2}\leq C_{p}(\Omega)^{2}||\mathbf{\nabla v}||_{L^{2}(\Omega)}^{2} $$
how can I continue from here? maybe the Rellich's compactness theorem help here?

Comment: What is the $L^2$ **semi**norm, if it is not the norm...?

Comment: @CalvinKhor The semi-norm of $L^{2}$ in the sense: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seminorm#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20particularly%20in%20functional,such%20set%20is%20a%20seminorm. and $\displaystyle ||v||^{2}_{L^{2}(\Omega)}=\int_{\Omega}v^{2}$.

Comment: Why would you say semi-norm when it is a norm?

Comment: @CalvinKhor Ok. I understand your question. The  problem ask me to try that statment for a semi-norm in $L^{2}(\Omega)$ a "weaker" statement. I know that's true for a norm as in your answer, but the problem is about the semi-norm in $L^{1}(\Omega)$. The problem is not about the norm.

Comment: This then brings me back to my first comment: **what is the semi norm? ** And why are you suddenly talking about L 1 one instead of L 2?? Maybe you mean H1 seminorm? Please edit the question to include this definition

Comment: @CalvinKhor in my last comment the correct is: $L^{2}(\Omega)$ sorry, for that new type. Returning to the problem about the semi-norm and the norm. In theory they gave me the definition of norm in $L^{2} (\Omega)$ And I need to prove this the problem statement for *any semi-norm* of $L^{2} (\Omega)$. I don't know if this makes sense or I need the definition of semi-norm in L2 to advance the problem.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Here, I'm confused, fortunately I found a link here where they seem to have the same doubt as me about the semi-norms in L2: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256270/poincar%C3%A9-inequality-using-h1-seminorm. That is why maybe you check that in my solution approach I start with an inequality that relates the semi-normal in L2 with the norm in L2. Again, if you see any errors in my understanding, I would be happy to read your comments.

Comment: @CalvinKhor From what I see, your solution is using the norm in L2, my question is: is the proof valid if we change the norm in L2, for any semi-norm in L2? Or for this question to make sense, do we need to define a specific semi-norm in L2?

Comment: The linked question is NOT talking about a seminorm of L^2, it is talking about the more or less standard seminorm on H^1 which is the L^2 norm of the gradient. I don’t know about your new question, but you should edit this into the main question, not in the comments

Comment: In addition, is it true that $N(u) \le C\|u\|_{L^2}$ for any seminorm $N$ on $L^2$ and some $C>0$? Its not obvious to me. And a further point, although it is not used in your proof: what tells you that $|v|_{L^2}>0$?

Comment: Apologies for the large number of comments but here are some extra pedantic issues: (1) Your definition of $\|f\|_{L^2}^2 $ is wrong when $f=\nabla v$ is a vector. (2) You also write $|f|_{L^2(\Phi)}$; given the above comments, is this a norm or a seminorm? And finally, let $T:D(T)\subset L^2(\Omega)\to\mathbb R$ be an unbounded linear functional. Extend by [Zorn's lemma](https://mathoverflow.net/q/31163/) to a linear functional also called $T$, defined on all of $L^2(\Omega)$. Then $N(u):= |Tu|$ is a seminorm and $N(u)\le C\|u\|_{L^2}$ is *false*

Comment: @CalvinKhor , after your comments on the semi-norm problem, I was able to understand the problem you were trying to tell me about. I really appreciate your patience in your hard work to help me clear up my confusion. I got the problem out of a collection of problems at the school in Paris where I studied, I guess there was a typo confusion when they proposed the problem. However, your comments are transparent to me. Again thank you very much, you are a nice user here at MathSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that your inequality is reminiscent of Poincaré. In fact, you can just follow the proof by contradiction of the normal Poincaré inequality. By usual density arguments we can assume $v\in C^\infty(\overline \Omega)$. Suppose such a $C_0>0$  did not exist. Thus for each $k\in\mathbb N$ we can find $v_k\in C^\infty(\overline\Omega)$ such that $\|v_k\|_{L^2(\Omega)} = 1$ and

$$\|v_k\|_{L^2(\Phi)}^2 + \|\nabla v_k \|_{L^2(\Omega)} \le \frac1k.$$

Then $v_k$ are bounded in $H^1$ and therefore after passing to a subsequence using Rellich compactness theorem, there is some $v\in L^2$ such that
$$ v_k|_{\Phi} \to 0 \text{ in } L^2(\Phi), \ \nabla v_k \to 0 \text{ in } L^2(\Omega),\ v_k\to v \text{ in } L^2(\Omega). $$  In
particular $v_k\to v$ in $H^1$ with $\nabla v \equiv 0$, and hence $v\equiv c$ for some $c\in\mathbb R$ ($\Omega$ is connected). Therefore, $v|_{\Phi} \equiv c$ in the sense of trace. By continuity of the trace map, $v_k|_\Phi\to v|_{\Phi}$ in $L^2(\Phi)$. But also $\|v_k\|_{L^2(\Phi)} \to 0$, so $c=0$. This is in contradiction with the assumption that $\|v\|_{L^2}=1$.

Comment: Thank you so much! :-)

Comment: @АлександрПальма glad to help!